# Copy Cells from a table in another table in another sheet

Tags: vba

I got this table (which in another version,  can have more/less columns, and in a different order, and inconsistent columns name), which usually is blank, but some id can have value like the one in the photo:
I decided to use numeric label for the columns of the table (as the columns don't have fixed names, but can vary), in order to avoid this problem

[image]

I need to fill this table with data from the db sheet (which have the same properties as the table but have all the record)

The order of the data in the table and db, it's not the same, and the IDs in the table can be or not in the db (or vice-versa), but I have to fill only the ID that are in the table and have records in the db

For those Id that have some data in the table and dont have value in the db, I should clear them in the table and let blank.
(I need to do this check and clean process, at least row by row, but if is better cell by cell x column)
ie let assume that the record 1003 has some value in the table and not in the db, so I need to clear the entire row for this record and let it blank (ie the data in db are the latest data, if there are no data for this record in db, it should appear blank in the table).

For some reason, I can't do, select all the range of the table and clear the contents of it, because I have some limitations, this is why I need to do the clear row by row or cell by cell

[image]

As I mentioned I need first to match the columns of the table with those of db, and after making the search and after make the copy and paste. While doing this process I need to transform the format of the date in the db to match the format of the date in the table.

How can I do all this process with VBA, and which is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean a `listObject`, or a simple range in a sheet? Are the headers in the same position, or in different positions?

Comment: a simple range, (that is not static, in terms of rows & columns, so I need to define it first)

Comment: And what about the headers? Are they in different positions? Which is the meaning of the first row ( 0  to xxx - 'columns order support')? Which is the last column in "db" sheet?

Comment: Are the IDs in "Report" sheet unique? Are they sorted as we can see in the picture(s)?

Comment: yes, they can vary, for example, the Date can be in column 1 in the table and column 2 in db, so this is why I should use the numeric labeling, Table.Col1=db.Col2, and after have the data I will change the number (in the column order support), because the order and the name of the columns in the db can vary

Comment: Ids are unique in  both,table and DB, but the order is not the same

Comment: I still cannot understand the (real) meaning of  'columns order support'... I can see in your pictures that both of them **follow the same sequence**. Will they be adapted to make a match? How do you suggest using them to be of any help? Then, you did not answer the clarification question regarding the last column in "db"...

Comment: Do the both 'tables' start from column A:A, or B:B?

Comment: this was an example, the Number (0,1...) should be considered as the label, so I can match the two tables, without transforming the structure of the db. Because the original name of the columns are non constant, so in order to have a constant name, I used the numbers

Comment: So, it is something to confuse us... Saying that **all headers of both tables are IDENTIC, but in a different order** and that first 'columns order support' is not really necessary, if a match can be found between the two sheets headers, would it be a correct understanding? You still not answer the clarification questions related to the first and last column in the two sheets to be processed... How would you translate this "the original name of the columns are non constant"?

Comment: i don't know, which is the last column of in the db sheet, because, it vary by of the source of the db. the only thing that I know is that the columns in the table sheet will be in db sheet, and I need to fill only these columns (because in the  db sheet can be even other columns)

Comment: and the tables start from different columns

Comment: I am afraid I will give up... You places a bad question in terms of clarity. If you need help, you must help us understanding what you really try accomplishing. How can you guarantee that the headers ar identic, if you do not even know how many will they be? How "the columns in the table sheet will be in db sheet" to be understood? The **headers** are identic, or only the columns must exist, but you do not know which their header will be?

Comment: it means that (id, name bdate, can be different in other source, maybe they are labeling like: CustID, Birthdate, CustName.....) so I need I first row to have constant name, so this is I use the number

Comment: I need to create a code that deal with different structure of the db and the table, one time 3 columns another time 5 column, and these columns maybe will not have the same order or the same name. In one case I will have only id/name/surname, in another db I will have id/name/surname/dbay/address

Comment: Then, I wish you success in creating such a structure! You will maybe find a more patient colleague able to deal with abstract issues you not being able to clearly describe them.

Comment: but anyway, we can assume that the tables are fixed, after I can deal with it, to adapt the code to my request

Comment: Your question is extremely bad, on my taste... You should clearly explain the context and try putting in our place, related to a logical solution to your problem. If there is not any **clear reference** and the context is only in your head, nobody can help you. 1. Is, **at least**, the "ID" column **always** the first (of the tables)? 2. Is the header always **on the same row** in both sheets/tables? In order to develop a solution able to work for any number of columns **you should supply, at least, a reference to be checked and based on what to determine the first column**!

Comment: Yes, the ID is the first column on both sheets, The headers are always on the same row in boths sheets,

Comment: OK. In such circumstances I can prepare an answer. I need the  confirmation that the column keeping `Date`  header will always be **bdate**. Basically, the code should search for the "id" 'marker' in both sheets, determine the first column and header(s) row(s) (now, they may be different per each sheet) and only after that start processing. Finally, it will format the `Date` column as it is in 'Report' sheet...

Comment: Yes, the Date header will be always bdate, yes the flow is like you describe

Comment: OK. Please, test my answer code and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It follows the above explained scenario. Besides what I said in my comment, you must note that **NO other cell containing ONLY the string "id" must exist in both processed worksheets. The code should be fast, placing the ranges in arrays, swapping columns and processing only in memory:

```
Sub UpdateReport()
 Dim wsR As Worksheet, wsDB As Worksheet, lastRR As Long, lastRDB As Long, cellID As Range, cellID2 As Range
 Dim firstColR As Long, lastColR As Long, lastColDB As Long, firstColDB As Long, rngRep As Range, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim arrHR(), arrHDB(), arrR(), arrDB(), arrCols(), arrSwapped(), colDateNo, dateFormat As String, k As Long
 Const DateHeader As String = "bdate"
 
  Set wsR = Worksheets("Report")
  Set wsDB = Worksheets("db")
  
  '"Report" sheet extracting data:
  'find the cell containg "id" string, to determine the first table row/column:
  Set cellID = wsR.UsedRange.Find(what:="id", After:=wsR.UsedRange(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)  'the cell where "id" was found
  If cellID Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No ""id"" header could be found in ""Report"" worksheet!": Exit Sub
  
   firstColR = cellID.Column     'first table column (in "Report" sheet)
   lastColR = wsR.cells(firstColR, wsR.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last table column
   lastRR = wsR.cells(wsR.rows.count, firstColR).End(xlUp).row                        'last row
   arrHR = wsR.Range(cellID, wsR.cells(cellID.row, lastColR)).Value2 'place the report table HEADER in an array
    colDateNo = Application.match(DateHeader, arrHR, 0) 'determine the column with Date number
    If Not IsError(colDateNo) Then
        'extract existing NumberFormat form the column keeping Dates
        dateFormat = getDateformat(wsR.cells(cellID.row, cellID.Column + colDateNo - 1), lastRR)
    Else
        MsgBox "Coundn't find any (necessary) column named """ & DateHeader & """...": Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'set the "Report" sheet range to be processed:
    Set rngRep = wsR.Range(cellID.Offset(1), wsR.cells(lastRR, lastColR))
    arrR = rngRep.Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing

  '"DB" sheet extracting data:
  Set cellID2 = wsDB.UsedRange.Find(what:="id", After:=wsDB.UsedRange(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  If cellID2 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No ""id"" header could be found in ""db"" worksheet!": Exit Sub
  
   firstColDB = cellID2.Column 'first table column
   lastColDB = wsDB.cells(firstColDB, wsDB.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last table column
   lastRDB = wsDB.cells(wsDB.rows.count, firstColDB).End(xlUp).row                        'last table row
   arrHDB = wsDB.Range(cellID2, wsDB.cells(cellID2.row, lastColDB)).Value2          'place the DB table header in an array
   arrDB = wsDB.Range(cellID2.Offset(1), wsDB.cells(lastRDB, lastColDB)).Value2  'place the range to be processed in an array
   
   arrCols = colsOrderDB(arrHR, arrHDB)  'extract an array of CORRECT columns order, related to `Report` sheet table
   If arrCols(0) = "" Then Exit Sub 'if any header is missing, the code exits
   
   'create the array containing the columns in the NECESSARY order:
   arrSwapped = Application.Index(arrDB, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arrDB) & ")"), arrCols)
  
  'process arrR array and fill its empty rows with data from the "id" sheet
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrR)
        If Application.CountA(rngRep.rows(i)) <> UBound(arrR, 2) Then 'check if NOT all the row is filled
           For j = 1 To UBound(arrSwapped)   'if not filled, iterate between the swapped array rows:
                If arrR(i, 1) = arrSwapped(j, 1) Then
                    For k = 2 To UBound(arrR, 2)
                        arrR(i, k) = arrSwapped(j, k) 'fill arrR with data from "db"
                    Next k
                    Exit For
                End If
           Next j
        End If
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array content at once and format the date column as previously it was
  With rngRep
        .Value2 = arrSwapped
        .Columns(colDateNo).NumberFormat = dateFormat
  End With
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Function colsOrderDB(arrR, arrDB) As Variant 'function to return the correct columns potition, related to "Report" sheet header
    Dim arrC(), mtch, i As Long
    ReDim arrC(UBound(arrR, 2) - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrR, 2) - 1
        mtch = Application.match(arrR(1, i + 1), arrDB, 0)
        If Not IsError(mtch) Then
            arrC(i) = mtch
        Else
            MsgBox "The header """ & arrR(1, i + 1) & """ does not exist in sheet ""db""!"
            colsOrderDB = Array(""): Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    colsOrderDB = arrC
End Function

Function getDateformat(rng As Range, lastR As Long) As String 'function to return the NumberFormat of the colum keeping Date
    Dim rngDate As Range, i As Long
    Set rngDate = rng.Resize(lastR)
    For i = 1 To rngDate.rows.count
        If IsDate(rngDate(i)) Then getDateformat = rngDate(i).NumberFormat: Exit Function
    Next i
End Function
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: need to digest it first

Comment: @nonUser I would suggest to firstly **try** it. Save a test workbook and play on it. In this way you will immediately understand if it is something to be digested, or you need clarifying other things before that... I tried commenting all code lines which could not be clear. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.